Movie about deciding not to live in a dream like world
Can anyone tell me what this movie is.
I watched the start of it years ago (90's / 2000) and would like to find it again so I can watch the full movie. 
I can only remember the start where there's a young women complaining to her mother in this dream / virtual world  that she doesn't want to live life like this. The AI (or something) says that she can anything she wants and I think she says she wants to live a real life (might be wrong on this bit). After which she comes out of this dream / virtual world and some sort of police come knocking at the door to arrest her.

Was this a U.S. movie? Did you recognize any actors/actresses?

I think it was a US movie. It might even of been a tv movie.

Do you remember anything about the appearance of the young woman? Hair color? Ethnicity? Also, anything distinctive about the dream/virtual world? Was it indistinguishable from the real world? Or was there some camera filter or something to make it clear to the audience that they were in it.

@Richard Make it as an answer.
